# Можно ли установить Sharepoint server на Windows 7-32 или win XP ?

Tags: windows, sharepoint

Про Вин 7-64 нашёл: [Установка SharePoint 2010 на Windows 7](http://www.oszone.net/11574/SharePoint2010_Install_Windows7). А вот про вин7 32 или xp нигде нет (если вообще возможно).

Answer (score 2):

Нельзя. Вот [ссылка](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee554869%28office.14%29.aspx).

Или выдержка оттуда:

In any development environment, you should use a computer with an x64-capable CPU, and at least 2 gigabytes (GB) of RAM to install and run SharePoint Foundation; 4 GB of RAM is preferable. You should use a computer with 4 GB of RAM to install and run SharePoint Server; 6 GB to 8 GB of RAM is preferable.

Following are the options:

- Install SharePoint on Windows Server 2008 Service Pack 2 x64 (or Windows Server 2008 R2 x64).
- Use Microsoft Hyper-V and install SharePoint on a virtual machine running a Windows Server 2008 Service Pack 2 x64 (or Windows Server 2008 R2 x64) guest operating system.
- Install SharePoint on Windows 7 x64, Windows Vista Service Pack 1 x64, or Windows Vista Service Pack 2 x64.
- Use Microsoft Hyper-V and install SharePoint on a virtual machine running a Windows 7 x64, Windows Vista Service Pack 1 x64, or Windows Vista Service Pack 2 x64 guest operating system.